# R: count the number of entries above a threshold, in at least X samples of the same type?

Tags: r, count, threshold, subset

I would like to count the number of row entries above a threshold in at least X samples of the same type (column ID)? Here is an example of what I would like to do:

Count the number of genes (g1 - g4) with counts higher than 5 in at least 2 cultivars of the same type.

```
Cultivar A A B B B
g1       5 2 6 7 10
g2       6 9 3 2 1
g3       2 1 3 4 5
g4       4 6 7 3 2
```

Counting will have to result in counting g1, g2, but not g3 and g4. 
Result = 2.
I know how to count the number of genes in two random samples and randomizing and subsampling the process:

```
#Filter for genes with values larger than 5 reads in at least 2 random samples
# Replace values >5 to 1
Gene_counts1=ifelse(RAW_gene_counts>5,1,0)
# Number of randomizations 100
MATRIX = matrix(NA,100,length(SAMPLE))
x=1
SAMPLE = c(10,20,30,40,50,60)
for(i in SAMPLE){
for (j in 1:100){
    columns = sample(1:ncol(Gene_counts1), i, replace = TRUE)
    random_sample = mapply(function(row,col)return(Gene_counts1[row,col]), col=columns)
    MATRIX[j,x] = sum(rowSums(random_sample)>=2)
    }
    x=x+1
}
MATRIX
colnames(MATRIX)=SAMPLE
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: does cultivar refer to the `A`s and `B`s or to the `g1`, `g2`, etc... ?

Comment: also, as a general concept on efficiency, you can simply use `Gene_counts1=as.integer(RAW_gene_counts>5)` instead of   `Gene_counts1=ifelse(RAW_gene_counts>5,1,0)`

Comment: Please supply your data in the form of the output of `dput(RAW_gene_counts)` or `dput(head(RAW_gene_counts))`.

Comment: Cultivars refer to As and Bs.

Comment: structure(list(V2 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2", 
"4", "5", "6", "A"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(5L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "6", "9", "A"), class = "factor"), 
    V4 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("3", "6", 
    "7", "B"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "7", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("CULTIVAR", 
"g1", "g2", "g3", "g4"))